# TFT display wiring on Sparkfun Pro Micro

Tags: display, tft, sparkfun

Please help me configure the wiring for this TFT display.

I’ve tried using the [Waveshare TFT display](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2inch_LCD_Module) with both the [Sparkfun Pro Micro](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640) and the [Raspberry Pico](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-pico/) but had very little success.  Only the backlight of the display lights up. The [1.3inch TFT display](https://www.smart-prototyping.com/1_3-inch-TFT-IPS-Display-Module-ST7789-SPI-240-240) works with the Pico using the connections above. I used a 2 inch display with the Arduino Uno. The screen works fine on the Uno.

I used Python [code from Erik's blogpost](https://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2021/02/raspberry-pi-picomicropython-st7789-spi.html) for the drivers which worked on the 1.3 inch display using the Pico, and [code from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/1-8-tft-display/breakout-wiring-and-test) to run the 2inch display on the Raspberry Pi. I attempted using Adafruit's code using the Sparkfun Pro Micro but only had backlights.

Below is the wiring connections list I started making while testing the screens. Some connections might be wrong as I am still figuring things out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are wiring wrong. At their [page](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2inch_LCD_Module), check the tabs, the connections are there for each board, also the example code.

[image: arduino]
[image: raspbi]